# innerHTML - Driving me Insane

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a simple JavaScript thing that's driving me bonkers.

Instead of the output being a link with 'subSectionNames[i]' as text (I've tried replacing with with simple "test" but the result is the same: It's spitting out the URI as plaintext: "domain.com/resume.php".  No linkification whatsoever.

Thoughts?

Controlled Assumptions for Testing:

```
var subSectionNames = Array("Hired Positions", "Contract Positions");
resume.addSubSections(subSectionNames);
```

(stuff comes in between)

```
this.addSubSections = function(subSectionNames) {
            subSectionHeading = document.createElement('span');
            subSectionHeading.setAttribute('id', 'subHeading');
            subSectionHeading.setAttribute('class', 'resumeSubHeading');
            for (var i=0;i<subSectionNames.length;i++) {
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.setAttribute('class', 'resumeSubHeadingLink');
                    link.setAttribute('href', '#');                 
                    var clickEvent = "showSubHeading('" + subSectionNames[i] + "')";
                    link.setAttribute('onClick', clickEvent);
                    link.innerHTML=subSectionNames[i];
                    link.innerHTML="test"+i;
                    subSectionHeading.innerHTML = subSectionHeading.innerHTML + link;
            }
            document.getElementById('leftInner').appendChild(subSectionHeading);
    }
```

Comment: You should probably try to refrain from doing `el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + etc`, as that makes your browser break down the DOM several times in an inefficient way.

Comment: Also, you can replace all those calls to *setAttribute* with direct property acess - much faster and less problematic, e.g. `link.href = '#'`. Note also the usual advice for links - they should really be links, so give them a real *href* or use a button or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set the `innerHTML` to a DOM object---it holds a string only! Instead, use `subSectionHeading.appendChild(link)`.

Comment: ohhhhhhh. I see. The problem isn't with the link script at all. Testing that now.